# How to create a generic function that supports two different types

Tags: typescript

I want to create a generic function that supports 2 different types, those types are not used interchangeably only one at time yet the function will serve as helper function to be using in both types.

```js
type  userType = {id : string; user : string}
type  adminType =  {id : string; admin : string}


const copmairByLoop = (firstObject: userType | adminType, secondObject: userType | adminType) => {
for (const key in firstObject) {
if (firstObject[key as keyof userType | adminType] !== secondObject[key as keyof userType | adminType]) {
alert('are not the same');
}
}
};


// use case examples 
const objectUser1 : userType = {id : '234234'; user : 'jack'}
const objectUser2 : userType ={id : '454366546'; user : 'max'}
// copmairByLoop(objectTest1,objectTest2) users are not the same...

// use case examples 
const objectAdmin1 : adminType = {id : '44433'; admin: 'joe'}
const objectAdmin2 : adminType ={id : '7778'; admin: 'alfred'}
// copmairByLoop(objectAdmin1,objectAdmin2) admins are not the same...




// my current refactor 
const copmairByLoop = <T, U>(firstObject: T | U, secondObject:  T | U): never => {
for (const key in firstObject) {
if (firstObject[key as keyof T | U] !== secondObject[key as keyof T | U]) {
alert('are not the same');
}
}
};
```

Please check the sandbox

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-7h6zsn?file=/index.ts)

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're trying to do. Why are you looping over the object properties?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you not satisfied with the "current refactor"?

Comment: Also your refactor will always (well, almost) alert because userType has a key 'user' which adminType doesn't, so you'll compare a string to undefined.

Comment: @SimonLundberg i want to check if there is a difference between the objects..

Comment: @yeahwhat the current refactor is erroring out in keys

Comment: Your types don’t even have the same properies. Why do you expect that they would ever match? Even if you have a user and an admin where both properties are the same the objects still aren’t identical because the properties are named differently. AdminType has `admin` and UserType has `user`.

Comment: @SimonLundberg exactly this is why i want to make it a global function where I can use it to compare 2 different users and 2 different admin neve ever user vs admin, so the function will be used to check if 2 admins for the sake of the argument are similar or if 2 users are similar but not to check if admin is same a user, so in the context of one type... but supports 2 different object types so i wont have to write another function for the admin.

Comment: Then why are you declaring the function has taking two different types?

Comment: @SimonLundberg I have updated the question, maybe it could clarify things

Comment: @SimonLundberg I just don't want to write 2 similar functions for each type of objects I want one that will do the required check and it will support 2 different types of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments, I think I understand what you want to do. My interpretation is that you want to have a single function that returns whether or not two users/admins are the same. The typical way of doing this would be to make a single function that takes a union of `userType` and `adminType`, like this:

```
type User = {
  id: string
  user: string
}

type Admin = {
  id: string
  admin: string
}

function IsEqual(a: User | Admin, b: User | Admin): boolean {
  return a.id === b.id
}
```

The downside is that this works by constraining the available properties to those that exist on both types (in this case `id`, but presumably each entry would have a unique `id` property anyway). It also means you can't check that they're both the same type, unless you add a `usertype` property to the types or something such.

The other approach is to use function overloading:

```
function IsEqual(a: User, b: User): boolean;
function IsEqual(a: Admin, b: Admin): boolean;

function IsEqual(_a: unknown, _b: unknown): boolean {
  const a = _a as User & Admin;
  const b = _b as User & Admin;
  // now both a and b have all three fields;
  // any that were not there before have the
  // value "undefined"
  
  // if comparing two Users, admin will be undefined on both,
  // and undefined == undefined evaluates to true, so that
  // gives the expected results
  return a.admin === b.admin && a.id === b.id && a.user == b.user;
}

const userA = {id: "a", user: "a"}
const userB = {id: "b", user: "b"}

const adminA = {id: "a", admin: "a"}
const adminB = {id: "b", admin: "b"}

IsEqual(userA, userB) // works; returns false
IsEqual(userA, adminA) // compiler error
IsEqual(adminA, adminB) // works; returns false
```

Note that unlike many other languages that support function overloading, Typescript only supports a single implementation body, so you need to manually wrangle the inputs to make them comparable.

Furthermore, I **strongly** recommend against looping over all properties with a `for (const key in obj)` loop, because there are no protections (either at compile-time or run-time) against the input objects having *more* properties than the ones specified by the type. If we do this, we get unexpected results:

```js
function IsEqual(_a: unknown, _b: unknown): boolean {
  const a = _a as User & Admin;
  const b = _b as User & Admin;
  
  for (const key in a) {
    if (a[key as keyof User] !== b[key as keyof User]) return false
  }

  return true
}

const user1 = {id: "a", user: "a",}
const user2 = {id: "a", user: "a", foo: "whee"}

IsEqual(user1, user2) // works; returns true
IsEqual(user2, user1) // works; returns false
```

Comment: the user1 and user 2 keys will always be the same, however the values might be different.. thus I want this function to tell me if the objects are similar in values... yet we have 2 different types of objects to run..

Comment: It sounds like the function overloading approach would work best in your use case. It will take two `userType` objects or two `adminType` objects, but not one `userType` and one `adminType`, and it checks all three possible properties.

Comment: You can't be sure the keys will always be the same. Typescript doesn't care if someone (or you) calls the function with an object with more properties. The Typescript compiler will complain if you call the function with an object without the needed properties, but it doesn't mind if there are more.

Comment: I am sure since the are types in advance, and I am comparing 2 typed function of the same type yet different values , maybe I am missing the point.

Comment: The point is that `const aUser: userType = {id: "whatever", user: "stuff", garbage: true}` is *VALID TYPESCRIPT CODE*. Typescript only checks that the objects have the required properties. It doesn't care if the objects have *MORE* than the required properties.

Comment: what do you think of this solution    const copmairByLoop = <T,>(obj1: T, obj2: T) => {
          for (const key in obj1) {
            if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
              alert('THERE IS A difference!!!!!!!!');
            }
          }
        };

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250694/discussion-between-simon-lundberg-and-nitroglycerin).